# LINQ to SQL: Circular queries

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a User class that has many posts and the post class has a user property. My problem is that in the repository to get User, I make a call to the Post repository to get all the user posts. In the repository to get Post, I also make a call to the User repository to get the poster. How do I handle something like this using POCO and repository pattern?

Here is the model.

```
public class User {
    public IEnumerable<Post> Posts {get; set;}
    /* Other properties here */
}

public class Post {
    public User Poster {get; set;}
    /* Other properties here */
}
```

repository code:

```
public IQueryable<User> GetUsers()
{
        return from u in context.Users
               select new User
                          {
                              /*Other properties */
                              Posts = postRepo.GetPostsByUserId(u.UserId)
                          };
}

public IQueryable<Post> GetPostsByUserId(int userId)
{
     //Well, I actually call GetPosts().Where(p => p.PosterId == userId);
     return from p in context.Posts
            select new Post
                      {
                          /*Other properties */
                          Poster = userRepo.GetUsers().Where(u => u.UserId == p.PosterId).SingleOrDefault()
                      };
}
```

If i make a call to either one, I get the error of `Object not instantiated`

PS. I just deleted a question targeting the wrong problem, so I made a new question defining the problem correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your doing it wrong ;) and ignoring Linq to Sqls ability to correctly generate joins for related entities:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399393.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.loadwith.aspx

---

EF Example:

```
var postsWithUsers = from p in context.Posts.Include("Users")
                     select new Post
```

Good documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx

Comment: The problem I have is that i use POCO. If I query a user inside the Post query, I have like 5 properties to rewrite this conversion from the entity mappings to the POCO. Same thing goes vice-versa.

Comment: Yep, that's the problem with L2SQL, you need left-to-right cloning for POCO's. Entity Framework FTW.

Comment: @RPM1984 could you write an answer and give some examples or a solution please? In EF.

Comment: Lucky for you in my current project im working on, i also have the concept of `User` and `Post`, with `One User` having `Many Posts`. However, an *answer* would be quite detailed. Maybe have a look at some of my other questions to get an idea. Essentially `User` and `Posts` are both seperate aggregate roots (DDD), therefore they have their own repository. When i need to get `posts for a user`, i usually already have a userid, therefore i don't need to query the user repository, i query the post repository with the user information.

Comment: And my original comment was alluding to the fact L2SQL must map a table to a auto-generated partial class, whereas EF allows mapping to POCO's. And the entire application works directly with the POCO's, therefore there is no left-to-right copying required. They pass through the POCO's, EF persists it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement your own repository pattern, on top of the repository pattern that is DataContext?  And you want your repository to effortlessly translate between the database types and domain types?

It looks like you're going to lose control over when database access occurs, by returning deferred queries.

Since the queries are deferred, your context will hang around for a while, so you're probably not disposing it after your unit of work.  You're setting yourself up for stale data.

```
public Domain.User GetUserWithPostsById(int userId)
{
DataLoadOptions myOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
myOptions.LoadWith<User>(u => u.Posts);

User record = null;

using (MyDataContext myDC = new MyDataContext(connString))
{
  myDC.LoadOptions = myOptions;
  record = myDC.Users.Single(u => u.UserId = userId);
}

Domain.User result = TranslateUserWithPostsToDomain(record);
return result;
}
```

Comment: elaborate what `TranslateUserWithPostsToDomain()` is? Is it an easier way of converting the generated entity to my custom written entity?